# Text in top right on an image

Tags: css, position

I would like to know how to build this example for all resolutions ( from 27 to iPhone ), I would like to put my text just above my bottom image -> [image: example]

```css
.content {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 0px auto 75px
}
.imgstyle {
  float: left;
  max-width: 800px;
  width: 100%;
}
.textcontent {
  text-align: left;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  z-index: 1000;
  width: 100%;
}
.hr {
  height: 1px;
  width: 50px;
  background: #282828;
}
.textstyle1 {
  font-family: 'GFS Didot', serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-align: left;
  margin-top: 30px;
  font-size: 40px;
}
.textstyle2 {
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 21px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
.textstyle3 {
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 21px;
  font-weight: 700
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <img class="imgstyle" src="http://www.facticemagazine.com/newsletter/img/test/1.jpg" />
  <div class="textcontent">
    <div class="hr"></div>
    <h1 class="textstyle1">Keep them<br/>closed</h1>
    <p style="textstyle2">Helen Molsted by Arron Dunworth
      <br/>Exclusive / November 11, 2016</p>
    <p class="textstyle3">Read more ></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to remove the `left: 0` and add `right: 0`.

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o3rxnfy0/5/)

Comment: ok, but i want my text stay at right with a max-width, is it possible ?

Comment: max width is still working, you just have to adjust the value for `right` a little bit to fit better

Comment: i added it but nothing changes, may be i'm wrong !!

Comment: when i click on your fiddle i still have my text at right of my page and not of my image ?

Answer (score 0):

Try it:-

```css
.textstyle1{
 margin:0px auto;
 float:right;
 }
```

```html
<h1 class="textstyle1">Keep them<br/>closed</h1>
```

or

```css
.textstyle1{
 margin:0px auto;
 float:right;
 }
P{
 text-align:right;
 margin:60px auto;
 }
```

```html
<h1 class="textstyle1">Keep them<br/>closed</h1><br>
 <p>Helen Molsted by Arron Dunworth
      <br/>Exclusive / November 11, 2016</p>
        <p>Read more</p>
```